# Rails search with pagination failing on page next page click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, will-paginate

Ok so i have a form

```
<form  action="/search" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="location_id" value="1" /><br />
<input class='small' data-datepicker='datepicker' name='start_date' type='text' value='03-09-2012'>
<input class='small' data-datepicker='datepicker' name='end_date' type='text' value='03-09-2012'>
</form>
```

and i have the route

```
 match "/search", :to => "locations#search"
```

and in my controller

```
def search
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
  start_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:start_date], "%m-%d-%Y")
  end_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:end_date], "%m-%d-%Y")
  @songs = @location.songs.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30, :conditions => {:play_date => start_date..end_date})
  render 'show'
end
```

All works perfect other then when i click on page 2 or next the page errors because i dont have the location_id or the dates in the params....any idea on how to fix this...i am using the will_paginate gem

Error

```
Couldn't find Location without an ID
```

Parameters:

```
{"page"=>"2"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add location_id params to your will_paginate view helper like this:

```
<%= will_paginate @some_objects, :params=>{:location_id=>@location.id} %>
```

Hope it helps.